# Access the host address of the RESTAdapter programmatically

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I would like to obtain the host address of the REST adapter in a controller or in a component.

I'm using Ember-CLI, and I set up the adapter as follows:

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://localhost:9000'
});
```

I am aware that this question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324972/get-restadapter-host) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20388235/how-do-you-access-restadapters-host-and-namespace-inside-a-route-or-controller), but none of those approaches work in the recent Ember 1.6.0.

I tried all of the following:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.prototype.url
DS.RESTAdapter.prototype.host
App.__container__.lookup('store:main').get('adapter.url')
App.__container__.lookup('store:main').get('adapter.host')
DS.defaultStore.adapter.url
DS.defaultStore.adapter.host
```

Is there any way whatsoever (no matter how dirty/hacky/nauseating) to do this? Thanks!

EDIT: The correct answer is to initialize the adapter with a value you can access from elsewhere, like [Kingpin2k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25496826/access-the-host-address-of-the-restadapter-programmatically/25496893#25496893) pointed out below. I ended up creating an object with constant values and refer to it in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`App.__container__.lookup('adapter:application').host`

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/978/edit

Honestly you should just define it as a property on your app, and use that property in your adapter as well, that way you can grab it off the app w/o having to do that.

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  applicationAdapterHost: '/foo'
});

App.ApplicationAdapter= DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host:App.applicationAdapterHost
});
```

As you see, you can just grab it using `App.applicationAdapterHost` whenever you want, easily

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/979/edit

Comment: BTW I agree using a common reference to a constant value both in the initialization of the adapter and when accessing it from elsewhere is the best option. I wonder why I haven't thought of that? :)

Comment: for some reason the headers property in my ember component ApplicationAdapter(imported at the top via ES6) is undefined **ApplicationAdapter.prototype.headers**

Comment: Will you create a new question with all of your information?